# How to see full url that Visual Studio request in web performance tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

So my problem is that I have recorded test sequence and saved it. At some point queryString parameters are extracted. But when I run my test, it fails and redirects me to error 500 page, however, if I enter paste url with extracted parameters manually in browser, than everything works fine. So my question is how can I view url which is given to a server to get a page ?

Thanks in advance,
Jānis

Answer (score 0):

In the results, You have a Tab called "Tables" where you can find all requested urls.